# healpy equivalent of alm2fits

Tags: healpy

I am wondering what is the equivalent of alm2fits in healpy.

Let's say I have 3 alms for T,E, and B in healpy, how do I export them so that they can be read by a fortran code trough fits2alm?

`hp.fitsfunc.write_alm('alms.fits',[alm_T,alm_E,alm_B])`

seems not to like a list and

`hp.fitsfunc.mwrfits(filename= 'alm.fits',data=[alm_T,alm_E,alm_B],colnames=['T','E','B'],keys=None)`

seems to save them in the wrong order, so that fits2alm raises a 
`'Inconsistent l^2+l+m+1 -> l,m mapping'`
error

Thanks

A.

Comment: it looks like `write_alm` supports only `T` alms. somebody should implement this, it would be great if you could implement it by submitting a pull request on github.

Comment: Otherwise, if you open an issue on Github with details of what needs to be implemented and a sample file created in fortran or IDL. Somebody else might be able to implement it.

Comment: Thanks Andrea, I may implement it by myself if I'll have more time later. I will open a github issue anyway.